# Convert FBX to to xml using C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, binary, fbx

I just want to make a simple windows form application that allows the user to select a .fbx file and then it will save as an XML file. I know how to use the select file dialog and XML serialization. Just stumped when it comes the FBX handling. I just need the Verts, triangles and first UVs. No animations or materials.

Anyway Here's the XML format I need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MeshInformation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <verts>
    <Info_Vector3>
      <x>8.785349</x>
      <y>7.7458005</y>
      <z>1.65082479</z>
    </Info_Vector3>
    <Info_Vector3>
      <x>8.785349</x>
      <y>0.427168041</y>
      <z>1.65079832</z>
    </Info_Vector3>
    // etc...
  </verts>
  <triangles>
    <int>0</int>
    <int>1</int>
    <int>2</int>
    <int>0</int>
    // etc...
  </triangles>
<uvs>
<Info_Vector2>
    <x>8.785349</x>
    <y>0.427168041</y>
</Info_Vector2>
// etc...
<uvs />
</MeshInformation>
```

Comment: Really need to see sample of file.  I don't think serialization is best way of going since it is a binary format and I don't think your xml format is in same order as binary.  I would use BitConverter to extract each field from binary.

Comment: A .fbx file is a file type that contains data about a 3D mesh used in games and other 3D applications. I did not create the .fbx file type. I simple want to use it.

Comment: I know what a fbx file is.  I couldn't find a sample to test my code.